# how can I use w3wp to start SharePoint applications from command line?

Tags: iis, sharepoint, w3wp

Can anyone tell me how to use w3wp to start SharePoint applications from the command line?
And provide me with a small example.

Comment: I would like to confirm with you whether your Sharepoint app is hosted on the IIS? and you want to start it with the CMD command?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT yes, it is hosted on the IIS, do I possible to start it from command?

Comment: Web apps work in a completely different way from desktop apps, so you should learn the actual process model via articles like https://www.leansentry.com/guide/reset-restart-recycle-iis The sentence of "use w3wp to start SharePoint applications" makes no sense.

Comment: What I say above may not be clear.  My purpose is to monitor the winapi's activities of this web application. To achieve this goal, I need to start w3wp with my own hook library. For example, I have an application that URL is HTTP://spse:44454/, it will start a w3wp process while I type this URL in the browser. And the process does not change when I reopen this website. Do I possibly achieve this action from the command line? That is important for me to start it with my hook library.

Comment: The things you mentioned in your comment are totally different than the original question. I am not aware of any way that could start the W3WP process when you type the URL in the browser which also includes the hook from your library.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I own a way to start a process with my library. for my methods, I need to pass two params, one is the w3wp command line another is my library. So the first step is to validate that the w3wp command line can start with a specific web application pool.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, no involve typing the URL, I just want to start a w3wp for a specific web application.

Comment: Command to start the App pool I have already provided you in my answer. You could try to pass it as a parameter in your method and see whether it works as expected. If you face any issues, you could inform us. I could help to check whether we could fix that issue.

Comment: do not work, I have passed this command to my inject function(this function can start a target process and inject my binary into this process). but I need to inject my binary into w3wp which is a real work process for SharePoint app pool, not inject into appcmd. So I think I should start a w3wp from w3wp command. like `w3wp -s 1668934745 -h C:\\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\config\\applicationHost.config -w \\?\\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\26670\web.config`, but this command can only start a w3wp process which not link our specific app pool. Do you know how to use w3wp command?

Comment: is your site correct in your command? Could you please inform us from where you got it? Have you checked if it starts the process then which app pool is getting started?

Comment: run `appcmd list sites`->`site id`, run `appcmd list config "SharePoint26670"`->config file. thanks for your reminder, it only starts the process, and app pool does not start.

Comment: What happens if you run this command `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd start apppool "AppPool_Name"` after starting the process using the commands you shared above. You could see whether it starts the app pool.

Comment: I know that command can start the process and application pool, but the actual process of the application pool is w3wp, we need to start the application pool from w3wp, then we are using our intercept library. In another word, our library supports starting with a real process, not supporting processes starting from another process.

Comment: I understand the working of your library. I would like to inform you at present we are not available with the W3WP command to start the app pool.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run the command below in the command prompt to start the site that is hosted on the IIS.

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd start sites "Default Web Site"
```

If you want to start the App pool then you could use the command below.

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd start apppool "DefaultAppPool"
```

Output:

[image]

To stop the site you could use the command below.

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd stop sites "Default Web Site"
```

Notes:

1. make sure you run the command prompt as an administrator.